# Fortran - Cython Workflow

Tags: python, fortran, cython, fortran-iso-c-binding

I would like to set up a workflow to reach fortran routines from Python using Cython on a Windows Machine

after some searching I found :
http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-c and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info

and some code pices:

Fortran side:

pygfunc.h:

```
void c_gfunc(double x, int n, int m, double *a, double *b, double *c);
```

pygfunc.f90

```
module gfunc1_interface
    use iso_c_binding
    use gfunc_module

    implicit none

contains
    subroutine c_gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c) bind(c)
        real(C_FLOAT), intent(in), value :: x
        integer(C_INT), intent(in), value ::  n, m
        type(C_PTR),    intent(in), value :: a, b
        type(C_PTR),                value :: c

        real(C_FLOAT), dimension(:), pointer :: fa, fb
        real(C_FLOAT), dimension(:,:), pointer :: fc

        call c_f_pointer(a, fa, (/ n /))
        call c_f_pointer(b, fb, (/ m /))
        call c_f_pointer(c, fc, (/ n, m /))
        call gfunc(x, fa, fb, fc)
     end subroutine

end module
```

gfunc.f90

```
module gfunc_module

use iso_c_binding

    implicit none
    contains
        subroutine gfunc(x, a, b, c)
            real,                 intent(in) :: x
            real, dimension(:),   intent(in) :: a, b
            real, dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: c

            integer :: i, j, n, m
            n = size(a)
            m = size(b)
            do j=1,m
                do i=1,n
                     c(i,j) = exp(-x * (a(i)**2 + b(j)**2))
                end do
            end do
        end subroutine
end module
```

Cython side:

pygfunc.pyx

```
cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "./pygfunc.h":
    void c_gfunc(double, int, int, double *, double *, double *)

cdef extern from "./pygfunc.h":
    pass

def f(float x, a=-10.0, b=10.0, n=100):
    cdef cnp.ndarray ax, c
    ax = np.arange(a, b, (b-a)/float(n))
    n = ax.shape[0]
    c = np.ndarray((n,n), dtype=np.float64, order='F')
    c_gfunc(x, n, n, <double *> ax.data, <double *> ax.data, <double *> c.data)
    return c
```

and the setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension('pygfunc', ['pygfunc.pyx'])]

setup(
    name = 'pygfunc',
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules )
```

all the files ar in one directory

the fortran files compile ( using NAG Fortran Builder ) pygfunc compiles

but linking them throws a:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _c_gfunc referenced
 in function ___pyx_pf_7pygfunc_f

and of course:

fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

What am I missing ? or is this way to set up a workflow between Python and Fortran damned from the beginning ?

THX
Martin

Comment: This is strange. Don't you call `c_gfunc` somewhere from Fortran without explicit interface, or in some other way as a Fortran procedure, not a C one?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question

Comment: not solving your problem, but in case you didn't know there is also an alternative that you can consider: f2py.

Comment: Never mind, it doesn't lead anywhere. Apparently Cython is not using your Fortran object file at all. I don't know Cython enough to help you. Iwas able to run your code using `ctypes`.

Comment: @steabert Also not solving, but I think `ctypes` is an approach much closer to `Cython`. The Fortran code could stay as it is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a minimum working example.
I used gfortran and wrote the compile commands directly into the setup file.

`gfunc.f90`

```
module gfunc_module
implicit none
contains
subroutine gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: n, m
    double precision, dimension(n), intent(in) :: a
    double precision, dimension(m), intent(in) :: b
    double precision, dimension(n, m), intent(out) :: c
    integer :: i, j
    do j=1,m
        do i=1,n
             c(i,j) = exp(-x * (a(i)**2 + b(j)**2))
        end do
    end do
end subroutine
end module
```

`pygfunc.f90`

```
module gfunc1_interface
use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
use gfunc_module, only: gfunc
implicit none
contains
subroutine c_gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c) bind(c)
    real(c_double), intent(in) :: x
    integer(c_int), intent(in) ::  n, m
    real(c_double), dimension(n), intent(in) :: a
    real(c_double), dimension(m), intent(in) :: b
    real(c_double), dimension(n, m), intent(out) :: c
    call gfunc(x, n, m, a, b, c)
end subroutine
end module
```

`pygfunc.h`

```
extern void c_gfunc(double* x, int* n, int* m, double* a, double* b, double* c);
```

`pygfunc.pyx`

```
from numpy import linspace, empty
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar

cdef extern from "pygfunc.h":
    void c_gfunc(double* a, int* n, int* m, double* a, double* b, double* c)

def f(double x, double a=-10.0, double b=10.0, int n=100):
    cdef:
        ar[double] ax = linspace(a, b, n)
        ar[double,ndim=2] c = empty((n, n), order='F')
    c_gfunc(&x, &n, &n, <double*> ax.data, <double*> ax.data, <double*> c.data)
    return c
```

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
# This line only needed if building with NumPy in Cython file.
from numpy import get_include
from os import system

# compile the fortran modules without linking
fortran_mod_comp = 'gfortran gfunc.f90 -c -o gfunc.o -O3 -fPIC'
print fortran_mod_comp
system(fortran_mod_comp)
shared_obj_comp = 'gfortran pygfunc.f90 -c -o pygfunc.o -O3 -fPIC'
print shared_obj_comp
system(shared_obj_comp)

ext_modules = [Extension(# module name:
                         'pygfunc',
                         # source file:
                         ['pygfunc.pyx'],
                         # other compile args for gcc
                         extra_compile_args=['-fPIC', '-O3'],
                         # other files to link to
                         extra_link_args=['gfunc.o', 'pygfunc.o'])]

setup(name = 'pygfunc',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      # Needed if building with NumPy.
      # This includes the NumPy headers when compiling.
      include_dirs = [get_include()],
      ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

`test.py`

```
# A script to verify correctness
from pygfunc import f
print f(1., a=-1., b=1., n=4)

import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(-1, 1, 4)**2
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, a, copy=False)
print np.exp(-(A + B))
```

Most of the changes I made aren't terribly fundamental. Here are the important ones.

- You were mixing double precision and single precision floating point numbers. *Don't do that.* Use real (Fortran), float (Cython), and float32 (NumPy) together and use double precision (Fortran), double (Cyton), and float64 (NumPy) together. Try not to mix them unintentionally. I assumed you wanted doubles in my example.
- You should pass all variables to Fortran as pointers. It does not match the C calling convention in that regard. The iso_c_binding module in Fortran only matches the C naming convention. Pass arrays as pointers with their size as a separate value. There may be other ways of doing this, but I don't know any.

I also added some stuff in the setup file to show where you can add some of the more useful extra arguments when building.

To compile, run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. To verify that it works, run the test script.

Here is the example shown on fortran90.org: [mesh_exp](https://github.com/arrghb2012/fortran90/tree/master/fcython_mesh)

Here are two more that I put together some time ago: [ftridiag](https://github.com/byuimpact/numerical_computing/tree/develop/Python/cython_wrapping/ftridiag), [fssor](https://github.com/byuimpact/numerical_computing/tree/develop/Python/cython_wrapping/fssor) 
I'm certainly not an expert at this, but these examples may be a good place to start.

Comment: THX, the explicit setup.py was the eye-opener

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.