# creating a python package with fortran using c_iso_binding and cython

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, cython

Is it possible to compile a python package using a setup.py file that uses fortran code with the workflow described in https://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-c?

In brief, the workflow described here is to:

1. create a fortran wrapper function that defines c_iso_bindings for a fortran subroutine
2. create a cython .pyx function that creates a function using the generated c code from step #1

Is it possible to compile the codes from both of these steps in a single setup.py file? The numpy distutils package seems to be best for compiling fortran source, while cython is compiled with its own distutils package.

The solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404060/fortran-cython-workflow) added explicit fortran compiler calls to the setup.py file, and uses the cython distutils package. This seems both a little messy, and to introduce the possibility that different compilers are used to generate the code.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in a portable way unfortunately, but if it's just for linux or mac, you can do it by adding custom link arguments pointing to a pre-compiled fortran binary (`-L/path/to/file -lyour_lib -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/file`) for the C extension. The fortran code would still need to be compiled separately through numpy.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like numpy has the functionality to compile fortran code and link to it as a library. Here is a minimal working example following gfunc in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404060/fortran-cython-workflow), but I want to leave the question if there is a better solution.

First, run cython to generate c code:

```
cython pygfunc.pyx -3
```

The setup.py file compiles the fortran code as a library, and links with the generated cython c code.

```
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
from numpy.distutils.core import setup

def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
    config = Configuration('pygfunc', parent_package, top_path)
    config.add_library('fort', sources=['gfunc.f90', 'pygfunc.f90'])
    config.add_extension('pygfunc', sources=['pygfunc.c'], libraries=['fort'])
    return config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(configuration=configuration)
```

This can be tested with a inplace build:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

After navigating to the local pygfunc folder, the following test script should complete without an exception.

```
from pygfunc import f
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(-1, 1, 4) ** 2
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, a, copy=False)

assert(np.allclose(f(1., a=-1., b=1., n=4), np.exp(-(A + B))))
```